# Spark Delta format on non-Databricks platforms

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

> To improve query speed, Delta Lake on Databricks supports the ability
> to optimize the layout of data stored in cloud storage. Delta Lake on
> Databricks supports two layout algorithms: bin-packing and Z-Ordering.

If you run on-prem (not in the cloud) and use the `delta` format with Spark, thus not on Databricks, can the Z-Ordering be used? Or is it only available on Databricks run-time?

My assumption is yes, but just want to be really clear as I do not have RHEL cluster at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z-ordering is supported only in the Delta Lake on Databricks Runtime.

**Update** Delta Lake 2.0 has announced the support of Z-Ordering

Comment: This is a year old answer, is it still a valid statement? If yes, when can we expect this feature in Open Source, any plan?